# Nuxt vue Layout - content rendering within Nav

Tags: html, css, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a nuxt/vue layout - pretty standard:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div><AppNavigationNoIntro /></div>
    <nuxt/>
  </div>
</template>
```

the `AppNavigationNoIntro` basically contains a `<header>...</header>`

But the content from my pages renders WITHIN the navigation for some odd reason:

[image: rendering within nav]

Happy to share more code but I'm not sure if there is something I'm missing here. Why is the "Hello" not rendering below the nav within the main page body?

My index.vue seems to render content fine using a default.vue layout. Dir Structure here:

[image: dir structure]